# Using mapping in PANDAS to do a automated Vlookup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use mapping to match column "Asset" from both dataframes (both dataframes are named "names" and "match") and then based on that match add the column "paid" from dataframe "match" to "names". I am trying to do this without merging if possible. Only using mapping.
Thank you!

Below is how I tried doing it but nothing is showing up on my names dataframe.

```
names['paid']=names.Asset.map(match.paid)
```

What I have is not giving me an error but its not adding anything.

Comment: Hard to help without a minimal reproducible example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
names = pd.DataFrame({'asset':[101, 250, 312, 632]})
match = pd.DataFrame({'asset':[100, 250, 127, 312], 'paid':[15,26,31,22]})
```

| index | asset |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 101 |
| 1 | 250 |
| 2 | 312 |
| 3 | 632 |

| index | asset | paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 15 |
| 1 | 250 | 26 |
| 2 | 127 | 31 |
| 3 | 312 | 22 |

```
match_asset = match['paid']
match_asset = match_asset.set_axis(match['asset'].to_list(), axis=0)
match_asset

100    15
250    26
127    31
312    22
Name: Paid, dtype: int64
```

```
names['paid'] = names['asset'].map(match_asset)
names
```

| index | asset | paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 101 | NaN |
| 1 | 250 | 26.0 |
| 2 | 312 | 22.0 |
| 3 | 632 | NaN |

Everything can be written in a single line:

```
names['paid'] = names['asset'].map(match['paid'].set_axis(match['asset'].to_list(), axis=0))
```

and avoid generating an intermediate Series, in case the data is too large.

The problem with your original version is that `match.paid` doesn't have `match.asset` as index. So, when you try to use map, it doesn't know which row from `match.paid` should be assigned to each row of `names.paid`.

If there are duplicates in asset, *and the price of those assets is the same*, you can use

```
names['paid'] = names['asset'].map(match.drop_duplicates(subset=['asset'])['paid'].set_axis(match.drop_duplicates(subset=['asset'])['asset'].to_list(), axis=0))
```

However, note that this is going to map the price of the first time a value for assets appear. So it may be a problem if two equal assets have different prices.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the same issue I am currently having. Nothing is being added to my column "paid" on the names dataframe. It is just blank

Comment: In my example not everything is blank. There're NaNs only for those cases in which Asset is different in both tables. But look at the second and third rows. I did my example this way because I don't know your original data.

Comment: @max2lax, if this doesn't work for you, please provide a [mre], including an example of the desired output.

Comment: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:


KeyError: 'asset'                        Any idea why a traceback would be happening?

Comment: You were correct on that. However, now I am getting this error. InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: If I drop duplicated values then some columns will not be able to index as they will not have anything within their asset column. Could I just duplicate the column and then drop values and run off that?

Comment: @max2lax: I added a solution for when duplicated assets also have the same price.

Comment: I legit love you. Thank you SO MUCH. Saved me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would serve your needs but I once created a function that behaves similarly to Excel's VLOOKUP (or rather XLOOKUP). Please see it below:

```
def table_lookup(data: pd.DataFrame, 
                 lookup_column: str, 
                 lookup_value, 
                 output_column: str,
                 value_pos: int = -1, 
                 errors: str = 'raise'):
    """
    Python implementation of Excel's XLOOKUP function

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : pd.DataFrame
        DataFrame on which the lookup is performed
    lookup_column : str
        Column used as a key for search
    lookup_value : TYPE
        Value searched in the key column
    output_column : str
        Column containing value for the given key
    value_pos : int, optional
        In case of more than one match, regulates which one shall be returned. The default is -1.
    errors : str, optional
        Regulates function's behaviour in case of an IndexError. The default is 'raise'.

    Returns
    -------
    Searched value for a given key

    """
    
    try:
        df = data[data[lookup_column] == lookup_value][output_column]
        return df.values[value_pos]
    except IndexError as e:
        if errors == 'raise':
            raise Exception(f'Output does not contain any values at position {value_pos}') from e
        elif errors == 'ignore':
            return np.nan
        elif errors == 'coerce':
            return df.values[-1] if len(df) else np.nan
        

# Usage:
# df['new_col'] = df['key_col'].apply(lambda x: table_lookup(mapping_df, 'key_col', x, 'value_col'))
```